# Javascript - Poly clip image on client

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to poly clip an image on the client/front-end. Once I obtain the points is there a way to clip on the client (ie w/o making a round trip to the customer) ?

AFAIK, canvas only can clip rectangles. Maybe there is a way that I do not know? Is there a lightweight canvas library that I can perhaps use?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canvas context.clip command will clip based on the preceeding path.

That preceeding path may be a polyline:

```
// create a path polyline

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(100,100);
context.lineTo(150,200);
context.lineTo(150,100);
context.closePath();

// clip into that polyline

context.clip()
```

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/R26Ms/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do customization on that also here is the example:
http://netplayer.gr/crop/

You can crop the image by your selection.